# Can I view my iTunes wish list in the browser?

Tags: itunes

Can I view my iTunes wish list in the browser ?

Can I - for example - copy the link of my wish list ?

Comment: How can I view it on iPad for example?

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes

Comment: I am so sorry ammarx, I just realized that I have iOS 7 on my iPhone and iPad and the feature that you mention is on iOS 7, but I did not realize that previous versions of iOS 7 do **not** have it. iOS 7 does have it though, there is an icon in the top right corner when you open the App Store that reveals your wishlist, but it is only iOS 7 :(. I deleted my previous comment so that others are not mislead.

Comment: Ok. It seems that iOS 7 has amazing features. Thank you.

Comment: Correction: it seems that iOS 7 has plugged some gaping holes ;)

Comment: Yes. I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for Google folks, it is not currently possible to view your iTunes Wish List outside of iTunes.